# RethinkDB: Try to add record in one operation

Tags: database, insert, duplicates, rethinkdb

I want to add a user to the database, but I'd rather do it in **one** operation instead of doing `r.table('users').get(id)` then inserting if the result is null.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
r.table('users').insert({
    id: email
})
.run(conn)
.then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
        // result.first_error contains a string message like
        // "Duplicate primary key `id`:\n{\n\t".........."
    }
});
```

However checking if `result.first_error` contains the word "Duplicate" seems a hacky solution.

Is this only possible to do in 2 operations (try and find the record with `get`, then `insert` if it doesn't exist)? Seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `conflict` function to `insert` and produce a custom error message, then do an equality comparison on that.  Something like `table.insert(doc, {conflict: function(id, old, new) { return r.error("conflict"); }})`.

Personally, though, I would just check whether "Duplicate primary key" is a prefix of the error message you get back, and if it is treat it as a duplicate primary key error.

Comment: Yeah I was concerned that the message might change but it's unlikely. Your first idea is working though so I'll use that thanks, it's pretty clean with an arrow func.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the `insert` doc https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/insert/, it has this section:

> conflict: Determine handling of inserting documents with the same
>   primary key as existing entries. There are three built-in methods:
>   "error", "replace" or "update"; alternatively, you may provide a
>   conflict resolution function. "error": Do not insert the new document
>   and record the conflict as an error. This is the default. "replace":
>   Replace the old document in its entirety with the new one. "update":
>   Update fields of the old document with fields from the new one.
>   function (id, oldDoc, newDoc) { return resolvedDoc }: a function that
>   receives the id, old and new documents as arguments and returns a
>   document which will be inserted in place of the conflicted one.

So you can do this:

```
r.table('users').insert({
    id: email
}, {conflict: 'update'})
```

Or other solution is to use `replace`, but passing the `id` in get, like this:

```
r.table('users')
 .get(email)
  .replace({
    id: email
  })
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case I want it to error if the ID already exists as I don't want a user account to overwritten. My problem is that there is no good way of knowing if the error was caused by a duplicate record, or something else.